# Python: Install Tesseract for Windows 7

Tags: python, ocr

My objective is to use OCR in Python 2.7 using Tesseract on a Windows 7 machine, but I am running into issues as for the installation process. I tried following the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270473/how-to-install-leptonicatesseract-on-windows-without-visual-studio-to-use-in-an) but the link to "tesseract-core-yyyymmdd.exe" and "tesseract-langs-yyyymmdd.exe" do not exist anymore and I can't find these .exe elsewhere online. Here's what I have done so far:

1. installed tesseract from its executable from official tesseract-ocr page.
2. installed via pip packages "wand", "PIL", "pyocr".

Now, if I do the following in Python:

`from wand.image import Image
from PIL import Image as PI
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
import io`

No problem loading up these packages but `pyocr.get_available_tools()` gives me an empty list. I am sure this has to do with the missing installation .exe files above. Where can I find them? Is it something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried to set up pytesseract and it works ! I have windows 10 and python 2.7 installed.

all you need to do :

1. Download Visual basic C++ from http://aka.ms/vcpython27 and install it (common installation step)
2. Download tesseract from python via this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract
3. Unizip the file.
4. Go to the directory which contains the unizip file
5. Run this command " python setup.py install "
6. (Additional) to test if it's installed, go to your python shell and run this command " import pytesseract "

I hope it works !! Note pytesseract is google based OCR, it works similarly to tesseract.

Comment: I did all; but it worked after downloading and installing directly from https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract

Answer (score 3):

**Step [1]** To install **tesseract** kindly visit

https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

The latest installers can be downloaded from here: 
*e.g.*, tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.02-20180621.exe, tesseract-ocr-w32-setup-v4.0.0-beta.1.20180608.exe, tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v4.0.0-beta.1.20180608.exe (64 bit)

**Step [2]** Download Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from the link given below
https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/6/796EF2E4-801B-4FC4-AB28-B59FBF6D907B/VCForPython27.msi

**Step [3]** Install **pytesseract** for binding for **tesseract** using pip

```
pip install pytesseract
```

**Step [4]** Furthermore you can install an image processing library in python, e.g., *pillow*:

```
pip install pillow
```

greetings!! you are done!! :)

Answer (score 1):

PIP is a package manager for Python packages

1. Open cmd run `pip search "pytesseract"`, you can see latest version
2. Run `pip install pytesseract` for latest version or `pip install pytesseract==0.3.0` for version you want.
3. In windows python cmd run `import pytesseract` for sure installed was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Install both and you are done

Binaries from:
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

Python Wrapper from here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract